# Sometimes spring boot is not able to load a service or repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat8

Whenever my Spring Boot app starts I need to do sanitise some data.
So I've overridden the following method from `CommandLineRunnner`:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
```

Here I just call a repository (and also tried with a service with class the repository), it works in a few cases, but in a few cases, Tomcat is not able to boot my app.
All I get from `catalina.log` is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

BTW: it works on my machine (OS X) but the issue only appears when it is deployed to AWS (tomcat8).

Comment: Have you tried to use embedded Tomcat which is provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes, it was included as well.